# Plugin not found while migrating cordova project

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am migrating an app from Cordova 2.2.0 to 3.5. I am using a custom plugin for iOS which is responsible for scanning a barcode. I have placed the code in a folder under the Cordova Library project.

I am calling the plugin using the following code:

```
var RedLaserPlugin = {
scanBarcode: function(successFunction, failFunction) {
  return Cordova.exec(successFunction, failFunction, "RedLaserPlugin",
                      "scanBarcode", []);
}
```

}

and... on loading the app,

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () { Cordova.exec(rlp_success, rlp_failure, "RedLaserPlugin", "init", []); }, false);
```

in config.xml file I have added the dependency of the plugin using...

```
<feature name="RedLaserPlugin">
    <param name="ios-package" value="RedLaserPlugin" />
```

But when I run the app its not able to bind the plugin to the xcode project and giving following:

```
-[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 159] FAILED pluginJSON = ["RedLaserPlugin1615451183","RedLaserPlugin","init",[]]
```

Tried multiple combinations to make it work but none of them did. Am I missing something?

EDIT: I have created a plugin.xml in folder like below:

```
<js-module src="www/RedLaserPlugin.js" name="RedLaserPlugin">
<clobbers target="navigator.RedLaserPlugin" />
```

=3.8.0" />

```
<!-- config file -->
<config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
    <feature name="RedLaserPlugin">
        <param name="ios-package" value="RedLaserPlugin" />
    </feature>
</config-file>

<header-file src="platforms/ios/Production/Classes/MainViewController.h" />
<header-file src="platforms/ios/Production/Classes/MainViewController.m" />
<header-file src="platforms/ios/Production/Classes/MainViewController.xib" />
<header-file src="platforms/ios/Production/Classes/MainViewController.m" />
<header-file src="platforms/ios/Production/Plugins/RedLaserPlugin.h" />
<header-file src="platforms/ios/Production/Plugins/RedLaserPlugin.m" />
<header-file src="platforms/ios/Production/Plugins/RedLaserSDK.h" />
<header-file src="platforms/ios/Production/Plugins/RedLaserPluginFiles/RedLaserOverlayController.h" />
<header-file src="platforms/ios/Production/Plugins/RedLaserPluginFiles/RedLaserOverlayController.m" />
<header-file src="platforms/ios/Production/Plugins/RedLaserPluginFiles/RedLaserOverlayController.xib" />
```

And tried to install the plugin using the cmd

```
cordova plugin add RedLaserPlugin.js
```

But its giving me the error in the terminal like:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your plugin.xml is not valid.

Here is a sample plugin.xml template that I have created for my custom plugins:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
    id="your_plugin_id"
    version="your_version">

    <name>plugin_name</name>
    <description>description</description>
    <license>Apache 2.0</license>
    <keywords>keyword_of_the_plugin</keywords>

    <!-- ios -->
    <platform name="ios">
      <source-file src="Plugin_source_file" />

      <framework src="required_framework" />

      <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*/plugins">
          <feature name="feature_name">
              <param name="ios-package" value="plugin_name"/>
          </feature>
      </config-file>
      <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
        <access origin="*" />
      </config-file>
    </platform>

    <!-- android -->
    <platform name="android">
        <!-- android-specific elements -->
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

Check the following [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/plugin_ref_spec.md.html) for instance

Answer (score 0):

I assume you get a new Xcode project generated from Cordova 3.5.

If that's correct did you add your plugin's sources to be compiled?

Go to Build Phases then open the Compiled Sources dropdown. Click + and add the missing plugin source which should already be in your plugins directory.

Comment: Files to the compiled sources is already added. Rechecked again. :-)

Comment: Do you have a valid plugin.xml for this plugin ? I had issues with a missing plugin.xml since the older versions of cordova did not require it.

Comment: Added the plugin still of no use. See the edited question